# docker images are not running after pull on ubuntu 18.04 what the fix?

Tags: docker

docker can able to pull images but unable to run them what may be the reason no logs or errors coming out of run command I am using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: please add the dockerfile to provide us more context.

Comment: How are you running the docker images you pulled? Your `docker run` or `docker exec` command. Please add details to your question or else we'll assume you're just pulling images and did not attempt to run them.

Comment: i have pulled an image and then run, I also tried to run directly also, in both case it is pulling the image but not running it and exit without any logs @tentative

Comment: i have simply pulled ubuntu and run it but not working, no docker file I am talking here @KrishnaChaurasia

Comment: @SubarnaSamanta How are you running it? You have to specify something to actually run when you start the container, like here where you open up a shell: `docker run -it IMAGE_NAME /bin/bash`

Comment: Thanks the last suggestion worked for me, I had implemented much before but just forgot to reply. Thanks for the support.